# Using maven to connect to a local project

Tags: java, maven

I have two projects in eclipse:

1. framework:  A general library used in several projects.
2. client:  A project that uses `framework`.

`client` is quite large, possibly larger than `framework` at this point.  I am using `client` as sort of a test fixture for `framework`.  I want to make a few changes in `framework` and test them in `client`.  Currently, I have to do a full build of `framework`, install it into a maven repo, and then rebuild `client`.

Is there a way to just have `client` point to `framework` directly on my local disk?  Any other hints for developing in such a situation (ie is the a better way)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify dependencies from the local disk using <systemPath> like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>example.logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-logging.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure if you can point to a directory that has a pom in it, but at least you don't have to deploy it into maven.

Comment: I knew there was a way to do this.  Thank you.

Comment: That is not a good way to manage your dependencies. If the mentioned framework is not a maven project already, make it one and install it to the local repository, and then a remote repository if you want to work from multiple machines. That way you will be resolving this dependency like any other.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis - The question was not what is the best way to do this is.

Comment: @marchaos - You are right. However, I felt it necessary to mention this because this is the first answer people see.

Answer (score 26):

Running `mvn install` on Framework will build it and install it in your local Maven repository (that is, the Maven repository on your local disk). When you run your tests in Client, Maven will automatically use the version of Framework in your local repository.

Comment: This seems like a better way to manage local dependencies than systemPath as it allows different packages to reference specific builds if you're using snapshot versioning.

Answer (score 4):

The m2eclipse plugin is fairly intelligent about Maven dependencies. If you have the `framework` dependency open as a separate project in Eclipse, I think it should use its code for `client` rather than the version in your repository. You might need to tweak your project settings if you're already using m2eclipse and it doesn't do this.